# Use regex to match all groups including own delimiter?

Tags: c#, regex

My matching token string is

```
> token >
```

so any text between > > is a match.

My string could be anything so for example:

```
(random text) > (some token) > (some token) > (random text)
```

So with the sample text

```
impossible 1 > possible 2 > possible 3 > impossible 4
```

I need all possible matches.

The regex

```
\>(.*)\>
```

only matches one group

```
possible 2 >  possible 3
```

When I need the following matches

```
possible 2 > possible 3
possible 2
possible 3
```

Comment: What have you so far? Have you got problems to build the RegEx in the first place, or with greedy settings? Or...? (Edit: The downvote is not mine.)

Comment: Is that the exact string you want to work with?

Comment: (>? ?[^im]possible \d+ ?>?) would be a crude first attempt, place this in your question as this is currently not showing an attempt.

Comment: `Split()`, `Split()`, `Split()` ...

Comment: That is just a sample string, not the exact. I will clarify.

Comment: are they always in the middle of the string?

Comment: no they could start or end the string also.

Answer (score 3):

Unless I'm misunderstanding, there doesn't seem to be a need for a regex here.

```
string input = "(random text) > (some token) > (some token) > (random text)";
List<string> splitList = input.Split('>').ToList();

//(optional) place the original input string at the beginning 
//like a regex group match would have 
splitList.Insert(0, input);
```

Comment: I didn't mention it in the question, but the actual seperators are free form also. But I might be able to use regex.split.

Comment: Even if they're free form you can pass a variable into the `Split` method above. Or do you mean that one input  could have multiple delimiters? (in which case, you might want to post an example in your question with the delimiters and what you expect as the output).

Comment: The split would also contain (random text) which are not valid matches as they do not begin with >

Comment: Also I need (some token) > (some token) as one of the matches.

Comment: You can use a string delimiter if you like and concatenate items in the list for your `(some token) > (some token)`. But without examples of what you want I don't really get what you're trying to do as the criteria seems to keep changing. Maybe someone else can help here.

Answer (score 0):

You can find all allowed elements with this pattern:

```
@"(?=(>[^>]+)>)"
```

Then you can create all combinations you want with a loop.

Example:

```
string subject = "text > token 1 > token 2 > token 3 > token 4 > text";
string pattern = @"(?=(>[^>]+)>)";
Match m = Regex.Match(subject, pattern);
List<string> items = new List<string>();
while (m.Success)
{
    items.Add(m.Groups[1].ToString());
    m = m.NextMatch();
}
List<string> results = new List<string>();

for (int i = 0; i < items.Count(); i++)
{
    string temp = "";
    for (int j = i; j < items.Count(); j++)
    {
        temp += items[j];
        results.Add(temp + '>');
    }
}
results.ForEach(Console.WriteLine);
```

Comment: I tried rewriting to question to be more clear. see http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17983556/use-regex-to-capture-spanning-groups