# possible to use regex to find all matches including its own delimiter?

Tags: c#, regex

I am trying to write an email subject line parser where the user defines their own parsing rules. The rules will match member names on the subject line and then use that as a look up. The catch is the member name might contain the parsing rule delimiter.

```
// This rule has defined that any text between > matches a member name. 
// Note the user can make up any parsing rule so this is just an example.
string sampleRule = ">{member}>";

    // left out parsing code. We have figured out we are looking
   // for member and the prefix/postfix delimiters.


string prefix = ">";
string postfix = ">";

// note that member>Name3 is a valid member name
string subject =  "Subject>memberName1>memberName2>member>Name3>EndSubject";
string pattern = "(?="+prefix+"([a-z].+?)"+postfix+")";

Match m = Regex.Match(subject, pattern);

while(m.Success) {
    // this is a possible member name
    Console.WriteLine(m.Groups[1].ToString());
    m = m.NextMatch();
}

// the output needs to be
// memberName1
// memberName2
// Member>Name3    

// It is currently

// memberName1
// memberName2
// member

// Note that spanning bad matches are ok, for example
// memberName1>memberName2 or memberName1>memberName2>member>Name3
```

Comment: If the last name is your only concern you could make the postfix optional: +postfix+"?)";

Comment: so does each member name actually include the word `member`?

Comment: no it could be tom > dick > harry > my>Name > where my>Name is valid.

Comment: What if your postfix is different from prefix? Will your sample subject be: `Subject[member1][member2][member3]` (you see 2 characters between each member), while when they are equal it is `Subject>member1>member2` which is only 1 character between 2 names (which is a contradiction or bad definition). I suppose you should use one delimiter instead of 2 values for prefix and postfix.

Comment: Another question which could simplify the answer would be, are your delimiters (prefix and postfix) a single character, or they can be multiple characters?

Comment: What's the role of `sampleRule` in your question? How does it specify that `>memberName1>memberName2` are 2 member names while `>member>Name3` is only 1 member name???

Comment: This can't be done with a regular expression.  You would need some other rule to determine what is a valid name and what is not.  Or just use a delimiter that can't be part of a name.

Comment: My actual question was is this possible with regex. I will change the title.

Comment: We do a database lookup on each possible match.

Comment: The pre/post fix can be any length or characters. We currently place no limits.

Comment: So in the case of `>member>Name3` which is ambiguous what happens if both `member>Name3` is valid and so are `member` and `Name3`. Usually you would escape the delimiter when it is not being used as a delimiter and this is probably the best way to go. Either that or forbid the delimiter from being inside the value (so if `a>b` is one of your values then you couldn't use `a`, `b` or `>` as a delimiter.

Comment: `>` in `member>Name3` is considered a prefix or a suffix?

Comment: Its the actual member name :P Thus the problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here's a fragile attempt to use regular regular expressions and recursion:

```
static class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        string prefix = ">";
        string suffix = ">";
        string subject =
            "Subject>memberName1>memberName2>member>Name3>EndSubject";
        var result = Find(subject, true, prefix, suffix).ToList();
        result.ForEach(item =>
        {
            Console.WriteLine(item);
        });
        /* The output is:
        memberName1>memberName2
        member>Name3                *match
        memberName1                 *match
        memberName2                 *match
        member
        Name3
         */
    }

    private static IEnumerable<string> Find(
        string subject,
        bool toggle,
        string prefix,
        string suffix)
    {
        string
            r1 = @"(?<=" + prefix + @")(?>([\w]*(" + prefix +
            "|" + suffix + @")[\w]*))(?=" + suffix + ")",
            r2 = @"[\w]*";
        var temp = Regex.Matches(subject, toggle ?
            r1 : r2
            )
            .Cast<Match>()
            .ToList();

        return temp.SelectMany(m =>
            temp
            .Select(i => i.Value)
            .Union(Find(m.Value, !toggle, prefix, suffix)))
            .Where(s => !String.IsNullOrEmpty(s))
            .Distinct();
    }
}
```

*Note: I'm not sure if in your example, the `>` in `member>Name3` is considered a prefix or a suffix.*

[EDIT] Here's another approach, which doesn't use regular expressions. It takes into account that the `>` in the `member>Name3` could be a prefix **or** a suffix:

```
var separators = new[] { prefix, suffix };

var firstResult = separators
    .SelectMany(s => subject
        .Split(separators,StringSplitOptions.RemoveEmptyEntries)
        .Skip(1)
        .Reverse()
        .Skip(1)
        .Reverse())
    .Distinct()
    .ToList();

var result = firstResult
    .Zip(firstResult.Skip(1), (a, b) =>
    {
        var l = new List<string>();
        separators.ToList().ForEach(s =>
        {
            l.Add(String.Format("{0}{1}{2}", a, s, b));
        });
        return l;
    })
    .SelectMany(s => s)
    .Union(firstResult)
    .ToList();
```